# Read /etc/passwd file with Java

Tags: java

Can you help me to read the content of /etc/passwd file?

I would like to read the file with Java and display the username and user home folder location.

```
vivek:x:500:500::/home/vivek:/bin/bash
raj:x:501:501::/home/raj:/bin/ksh
ash:x:502:502::/home/ash:/bin/zsh
jadmin:x:503:503::/home/jadmin:/bin/sh
jwww:x:504:504::/htdocs/html:/sbin/nologin
wwwcorp:x:505:505::/htdocs/corp:/sbin/nologin
wwwint:x:506:506::/htdocs/intranet:/bin/bash
scpftp:x:507:507::/htdocs/ftpjail:/bin/bash
rsynftp:x:508:508::/htdocs/projets:/bin/bash
mirror:x:509:509::/htdocs:/bin/bash
jony:x:510:510::/home/jony:/bin/ksh
amyk:x:511:511::/home/amyk:/bin/ksh
```

Is this possible with Java?

EDIT

Here is my proposal

```
public void readLinuxUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/etc/passwd"));
            String str;
            str = in.readLine();
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] ar = str.split(":");
                String username = ar[0];
                String homedir = ar[6];

            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File Read Error");
        }
    }
```

But how I can read the home directory after ::?

Comment: Ofcourse it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What issues did you run into?

Comment: you need read permission of this file, try to run your java process with admin privileges.

Comment: read data line-by-line (`FileReader + BufferedReader`), split using one or more `:`.

Comment: I'm new to Java. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: well how you tried to read the file? there are lots of different ways . e.g using FileReader class

Comment: Can you show me some example with Java 8?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because user is asking for code without any efforts

Comment: @PeterPenzov google: read a file with java, it gives you tons of example

Comment: `new to java` is not an excuse to get the work done by someone else

Comment: I found many examples but the question is how I can get only the values that I need?

Comment: You could use [BufferedReader#readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) and then split using [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I do not have enough reputation to comment yet, but there's a possible bug in your code (unless you intended to exclude the root username), because the first readLine command reads the first line while the readLine at the beginning of the loop reads the next line.

Comment: Yes just remove the first readLine command above the loop. I have tested it okay.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're asking me. All you need to do is remove this line
    str = in.readLine();
from the example method readLinuxUsers

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't it be?  /etc/passwd is a file like any other on the system.  Just open in read-only and parse the text for the information you want.  In this case, /etc/passwd is several independent lines, each with fields delimited by a colon, ':'.  The field you want is username (the first) and home directory (the sixth).  Notice the :: means there is an empty field there.

Comment: I updated my post. Is it correct? I don't have a Linux box to test it?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Are you able to compile java code? If yes then create a file with your example input and test with that. You don't have to test on a Linux box.